# Why is the bootstrap navbar not appearing for this Ruby on Rails page?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using a Bootstrap 4 album template for my products page and the navbar collapse section does not appear. It should look something like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

Have I looked at Chrome DevTools? Yes, and the css is in there.

Have I played musical chairs with the application.js file, yes and nothing happened, it currently looks like this:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
```

My products.scss file looks like this:

```
// Place all the styles related to the products controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";

body {
  min-height: 75rem; /* Can be removed; just added for demo purposes */
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
  padding-top: 6rem;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.jumbotron p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  max-width: 40rem;
}

.album {
  min-height: 50rem; /* Can be removed; just added for demo purposes */
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  padding: .75rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border: 0;
}

.card > img {
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: 85%;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

footer p {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}
```

I haven't done a @import bootstrap-sprockets because the GitHub guide on Bootstrap 4 beta did not instruct me to do so.

This is the view/shared/_product_nav.html.erb partial:

```
<div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 py-4">
            <h4 class="text-white">Woodbury Farmers Market</h4>
            <p class="text-muted">Add some information about the products below, the author, or any other background context. Make it a few sentences long so folks can pick up some informative tidbits. Then, link them off to some social networking sites or contact information.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-4">
            <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <%= link_to "Home", root_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
              <%= link_to "Products", products_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
              <%= link_to "Categories", categories_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the views/layouts/product.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title><%= @page_title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <meta name="keywords" content="<% @seo_keywords %>" >

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Start of Nav -->
    <%= render "shared/product_nav" %>
    <!-- End of Nav -->

    <!-- Start of Jumbotron -->
    <section class="jumbotron text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Album example</h1>
        <p class="lead text-muted">Something short and leading about the collection below—its contents, the creator, etc. Make it short and sweet, but not too short so folks don't simply skip over it entirely.</p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Main call to action</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary action</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End of Jumbotron -->

    <!-- Start of album, container and row elements -->
    <div class="album text-muted">
      <div class="container">
          <%= login_helper %>

          <%= yield %>

          <!-- Start of footer -->
          <footer class="text-muted">
            <div class="container">
              <p class="float-right">
                <a href="#">Back to top</a>
              </p>
              <p>Album example is &copy; Bootstrap, but please download and customize it for yourself!</p>
              <p>New to Bootstrap? <a href="../../">Visit the homepage</a> or read our <a href="../../getting-started/">getting started guide</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </footer>
          <!-- End of footer -->

          <%= render "shared/nav", location: 'bottom' %>

          <%= source_helper("application") %>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of album, container and row elements -->


  </body>
</html>
```

I removed turbo-links from application.js and from gem file and updated precompiled rails asset pipeline.

What other steps could I consider? What could be going on?

Comment: Forget the `jumbotron` section for now.... Why do you have a `#navbarHeader`, with `.nav-links`, and yet you have only defined a CSS style for `.navbar`? What HTML get generated for **that section** of the page?

Comment: You don't have an element with `navbar` class in your html page..

Comment: @TomLord, the #navbarHeader is part of the album template from Bootstrap 4 beta and so is the SCSS styles you see above. The nav-links class is a class I created.

Comment: Could this be a bug with the album css and index template in Bootstrap 4 beta? When I go to Chrome devtools, I do see the css classes that have to do with the nav menu and I can manipulate them and it appears its being pulled from bootstrap css library but why doesn't it appear on my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add the whole navbar element to your navbar partial, you are missing this piece:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Album</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I believe once you add that, your site will be looking how you want it.